# Connect from container to localhost

Tags: kubernetes, args

I created a pod and try to connect from that pod to localhost. How is possible with the help of container arguments connect to localhost ?

Comment: try using the host IP, for instance in my PC is 192.168.0.X

in mac use ifconfig for grabbing such value

Comment: i use katacoda.com in this link ( https://www.katacoda.com/courses/kubernetes/playground) and when i type ifconfig it return me many lines but the correct address should be 127.0.0.1.  In this way i can just use args: ["/bin/sh","-c","127.0.0.1"] and will be connected to localhost ?

Comment: What do you mean exactly? You want to connect to the host your Kubernetes pod is residing? Can you explain better the concept? Are you considering the fact that in a Kubernetes cluster you might have many nodes and this communication isn't going to happen seamlessly? 

Please share as much information you can so it will be easier to understand and find a solution for your scenario.

Answer (score 3):

You can always execute:

```
kubectl port-forward <pod-name> port:port
```

Check more here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/port-forward-access-application-cluster/.

If you don't want to use port forwarding, then you need to expose your POD with a service. Read more here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/connect-applications-service/